# Polymorphic association: NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

NoMethodError in PostsController#create
undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass

Posts#controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    # before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
    before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy
    before_action :find_postable, except: [:index]

    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = @postable.posts.new post_params 
        if @post.save
            redirect_to :back, notice: 'Your comment was successfully posted!'
        else
            redirect_to :back, notice: "Your comment wasn't posted!"
        end
    end

    def destroy
        Post.find(params[:id]).destroy
        redirect_to posts_path#, notice: "Post successfully deleted"
    end

    def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        if @post.update_attributes(student_params)
            redirect_to post_path
        else 
            redirect_to edit_post_path
        end
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find (params[:id])
    end 

    private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:content, :image, :document, :audio, :video, :classroom_id)
    end

    def correct_user
      @post = current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @post.nil?
    end

    def find_postable
      @postable = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id]) if params[:post_id]
      @postable = Classroom.find_by_id(params[:classroom_id]) if params[:classroom_id]
    end
```

Here is the post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :classroom

  belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :posts, as: :postable
end
```

Here is the classroom model (it belongs to the class and this is selected in the new post form"

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, as: :postable
  belongs_to :teachers
  # belongs_to :students
```

Posts in Schema.rb

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
    t.integer  "classroom_id"
    t.integer  "postable_id"
    t.string   "postable_type"
  end
```

I've tried many things with no success, I'm not quite sure why I'm getting this error. I'm following a video and trying to apply it to my existing post model but am still having trouble. Thanks

New Post Form:

```
<%= form_for :post, html: { multipart: true, class: "post-form" }, url: posts_path do |f| %>

  <h4>Choose a Classroom</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_select :classroom_id, current_user.classrooms, :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <h4>Write a post</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <h4>Attach Files</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

For a post reply

```
<li>
  <%= post.content %> -

  <%= form_for [post, Post.new] do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Add a Reply" %><br/>
      <%= f.submit "Reply"  %>
      <% end %>

</li>
```

Comment: Where is `@postable` set?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what that is, this is my first time with polymorphic associations. I do have a find_postable method that I"ll post right away.

Comment: Pleas post your complete controller, it seems you are missing some callback.

Comment: @ postable.posts this is the problem, since @ postable is nil then nil.posts showing an error

Comment: I posted my whole controller, I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Maybe you are not passing the parameter `post_id`, or the one your are passing is not in your db, thus making `@postable` nil. Can you post your log with your params?

Comment: Parameters: {"utf7"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bunchofletters==", "post"=>{"classroom_id"=>"1", "content"=>"hello"}, "commit"=>"Add Post"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:15:in `create'

Comment: That's the problem, look at your parameters, there is no `post_id`, you need to send it so this line `Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id])` works. Otherwise you will always get `nil` in `@postable`.

Comment: How are you making the request? I guess that you use a form, can you post that code too?

Comment: @MaxLeoTony I see the error now, please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `find_postable` method, specifically in this line:

```
@postable = Classroom.find_by_id(params[:classroom_id]) if params[:classroom_id]
```

You are trying to fetch `classroom_id` from `params` (i.e. `params[:classroom_id]`) but that key (`classroom_id`) exists within `post` key in your parameters hash:

```
Parameters: {
  "utf7"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"bunchofletters==", 
  "post"=>{
    "classroom_id"=>"1",
    "content"=>"hello"
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Add Post"
}
```

To fix this, change `params[:classroom_id]` to `params[:post][:classroom_id]` in `find_postable` method:

```
def find_postable
  @postable = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id]) if params[:post_id]
  @postable = Classroom.find_by_id(params[:post][:classroom_id]) if params[:classroom_id]
end
```